# is there an online tool for solving equation of a line?

Tags: analytic-geometry, online-resources

I have as input two points. But the input points contain variables (constant references).

I've seen some tools online but they require numeric values.

The two given points are specified by constant expressions. You can assume: P1=(expr1, expr2 ), P2=(expr3, expr4) where exprn is some sum or product combination of constants a, b and c or a numeric. For example expr1 can be a+b, expr2 can be 2b and so on.

The problem can definitely be solved by hand, and its not a particularly difficult problem but my question is whether it can be automatically solved an online tool.

For example, if I give 2 points:  (a,0) and (b,c)

I'd like to get the a simplified answer like:

> $$c x + (a-b)y - a c = 0$$

Comment: Can you give an example of exactly the type of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Unless I haven't understood, you definitely don't need anything fancy for that; just compute the slope $m = \frac{\text{expr4 $-$ expr2}}{\text{expr3 $-$ expr1}}$ and use the point-slope equation for a line $y = m(x - x_1) + y_1$, where you can use your expr1 and expr2 for $x_1$ and $y_1$ respectively.

Comment: @pjs36 looks like we were thinking along parallel lines. :)

Comment: @mweiss +1 for the pun, and to your answer!

Comment: yes, it can definitely be solved by hand, and its not a particularly difficult problem but my question is whether it can be automatically solved an online tool.

Comment: What simplification are you expecting? The answers from pjs36 in the comment and mweiss in an answer are as far as algebra will take you without knowing the structure of the expressions.

Comment: @ross - I've updated original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [ask Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=line%20through%20%28a%2B2b%2C3a%29%20and%20%282a-b%2C3a%2B4b%29) something like:

> line through (a+2b,3a) and (2a-b,3a+4b)

and it will provide you with the answer

> $$y = (3 a^2-13 a b-8 b^2)/(a-3 b)+(4 b x)/(a-3 b)$$

as well as tell you that:

> x-intercept: $ -\frac{3 a (a-3 b)}{4 b} +a+2 b $
>
> y-intercept: $\frac{3 a^2-13 a b-8 b^2}{a-3 b}$
>
> slope: $\frac{4 b}{a-3 b}$

Answer (score 3):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) will do many kinds of symbolic computation.

Comment: can you share an example of how you would input the problem into wolfram alpha?

Comment: Not without an example of the problem you are trying to solve.  I don't know if Alpha will solve it, because I don't know what the problem is.  I posted this because it is where I go for symbolic computation on the web. -1 for asking for help without thinking about what information the helpers would need to help the way you want.   Alex S pointed out that problem.

Comment: I specified two points are given and that their values are specified by constant expressions. You can assume: P1=(expr1, expr2 ), P2=(expr3, exp4) where exprn is some sum or product combination of constants a, b and c or a numeric. For example expr1 can be a+b, expr2 can be 2b and so on. Does this clarify?

Comment: Absolutely not.  It seems like you are paranoid about exposing the problem, either for (imagined)  competitive reasons or because of fear of being embarrassed.  What is your input and what form do you want the output to take?

Comment: Please provide a *specific* example of the kind of problem you are trying to solve, not just a general description of the type of problem.

Comment: @Ross, I am not being paranoid or anything. The problem is precisely as I have stated. The points are expressed as constant expressions. What is vague about that?

Comment: @mweiss, the problem is exactly as I have stated it. Nothing mysterious. I just want to find the equation of a line where two points are given. Its not a difficult problem I know but one that I would just like to be able to see if I can automatically calculate.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, it's hard to answer this question without more details.  However, if $P_1=(expr1,expr2)$ and $P_2=(expr3,expr4)$, then the slope of the line joining the two points is given by
$$m=\frac{expr4-expr2}{expr3-expr1}$$
and the line through the two points can be written in the form
$$y = \frac{expr4-expr2}{expr3-expr1}(x-expr1) + expr2$$

I suppose you can feed that into Wolfram Alpha if you like and it can simplify the result for you.

Comment: Given the history I have to hit this with a -1.  It is correct, but OP seems to be intentionally being so vague to be noncooperative.  My resistance to the -1 is that maybe it won't help OP because s/he doesn't know what s/he wants.

Comment: yes, it can definitely be solved by hand, and its not a particularly difficult problem but my question is whether it can be automatically solved an online tool.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "solved".  If the points are $(a+3b,5b-2^a)$ and $(4a-3b,3a-2^b)$ would you be content with the answer $y=\frac{3a-5b-2^b+2^a}{4a-3b-a-3b}(x-a-3b)+5b-2^a$?  Or are you hoping for something else?

Comment: (By the way:  the above is an illustration of what a "specific example" looks like.  If this is not representative of the class of problem you are thinking about, please provide a specific example of your own.)

Comment: @mweiss your answer is exactly what I needed.